# Android: Is it possble to use MediaCodec on android 4.0.4(api level 15)?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Is it possble to use MediaCodec on android 4.0.4(api level 15)?
MediaCodec Min api level is 16, but I need to use on level 15.
Is there any way to use MediaCodec on android 4.0.4 except for Upgrading android OS?

Comment: Don't think so 16 is the lowest level. You would have to program all the MediaCodec to work with 15. I would just bump up to 16 rather than use 15.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. when I use android studio, it says 'MediaCodec min sdk level is 16'. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I have some reason don't bump up to 16. Company says that they can't upgrade android version of equipment. But, I need to use android media encoder. When I search Internet, a lot of ways exists. But so difficult...

Comment: You have to use the Android SDK level 16 in order to use MediaCodec, Now the only way around it is to look for another codec to run you video. What type are your videos? mp4 off of youtube?

Comment: Android is at 23 or 24 now, I don't think its a good idea to use such an old version.

Comment: Company uses 15 and they say can't upgrade. I also want to upgrade... but no way.. I use h.264 for real time streaming android to android. I think ffmpeg with libstagefright is only way..

Comment: your company won't buy you a new phone? The old phone won't work as well if you try to debug and use it on newer phones, I feel your company has painted you into a wall

Comment: equipment is not phone but special equipment so they says can't upgrade because of stability..

Comment: what kind of special equipment? A video recorder?

Comment: Equipment has many function. Real time streaming is just one part. Equipment uses arm-based mobile cpu.

Comment: I think your company has shot itself in the foot. I would look into other Media third party wears. I don't know off my head of any. What functions will you use from the MediaCodec

Comment: I need two parts. encode decode. so now I made FFmpeg with libstagefright using android ndk for arm and will make encoder decoder.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to do that.